# Probability and integration

Tags: probability, integration

Compute $E[e^{tX}]$ where $X ∼ \mathcal{N} (0, 1)$. [Hint: Complete the square in the exponent.]

Do we set up the integral from $0$ to $1$? Then how do you solve this integral?

Comment: Note that this is the moment generating function of a (standard) normal distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: You need to compute $$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}+tx}\,dx$$

Note that $-\dfrac{x^2}{2}+tx=-\dfrac{1}{2}(x^2-2tx)$. Now complete the square.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26418/discussion-on-answer-by-cristopher-probability-and-integration).

Answer (score 1):

Let $f\left(x\right)$ denote the probability density of $X$. Note that $X$ can take values from $-\infty$ to $\infty$; that is the range of the integral (not $0$ to $1$). The expectation is
$$
E\left[e^{tX}\right]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\left(x\right)e^{tx}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}/2}e^{tx}dx.
$$